# Is it possible to put a single field of views in panels?

Tags: views, panels

There is an existing views with a few fields output. I would like to put one of these fields in panels. Can I get it directly in Add Content of panels?

If it is impossible, what is the best way to put a single field in panels?

Comment: create a view block with a single field, then add to panels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a single field directly from panels using **Add Content**, for this you may need to add a context with your entity.

- use **Arguments** option to pass an entity id from url argument and load dynamically context based on that entity;
- use **Context** option to manually specific a entity id to load its context;

You can check node view page as example, which has node context by default.